# UK Ancestry Visa - Getting my Scottish Grandparents Birth Certificate

Tags: ancestry-visas

I am looking at working in the UK, I am seeking my Grandparents Birth Certificate.
He was born in Scotland in 1901, however we have been told that his original Birth "certificate or records" were destroyed in a fire in Glasgow.
He sailed and remained in Australia in 1923 as a singer and the company he came to Australia with had to vouch that he was who he said he was and birth dates.
We have no knowing who his parents were as he did not talk about them.

Would anyone know how to go around this to receive the Ancestry Visa?

Comment: Note that if the answers here aren't sufficient and you need to make a follow-up question, we have a [sister site dedicated to genealogy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/) whose members probably know more than us about birth certificates. If you do post a follow-up question there, please link back to this one and edit this question to link to the follow-up so that answerers can see the full context.

Answer (score 1):

Who told you this?

For a comparatively modern record it would be very unlikely for all copies of the Register to have been destroyed.

You can search registers online and order copies at

https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/